# Trouble centering page links within nav-bar

Tags: html, menu, center, nav

I've been searching all over, and found plenty of results, but not getting the effect or any change at all as to what I'm seeking. Also, reaching out to the author hasn't refunded an answer yet either. Atop my blog is the norm *about us* and different "tabs" that click to linked pages. However, for the life of me, I can't get the to be centered withing the provided bar space. Now, firstly, there was a search-bar widget on the right of the tabs in the empty space now, because I found that code and deleted it. That may be the cause right there, not getting rid of EVERYTHING needed to use that space for the tabs in the full width of the "nav-bar". I've tried just adding .PageList styles to CSS, using google chrome to inspect the elements and see live changes is just becoming frustrating. I believe I'm at the right spot or around it with "nav-bar", "primary-nav", "main-menu-nav" but dang it's just not working out. It may not even be possible for all I know, with this custom template from SoraTemplates.

So here's hoping to find a smart(er) individual out there who can take a peak and show me the light. Blog is located at [www.modernvintageus.com](http://www.modernvintageus.com/)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

P.S Keep the laughter to a minimum if my HTML looks like a storm hit it, I'm learning all on my own here.

*EDIT*
Adding code snipet (from what I believe is where I need to be) per request and for ease...

```
    .PageList li.selected a {font-weight:normal}
.PageList li a:hover {color:#aaaaaa}
#access{margin-top:20px}
#access li{float:left}
#access a{color:rgb(220, 228, 61);font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;text-shadow:0 1px 1px #111}
#nav-bar{padding:0 10px;background:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RC90VnZa6gg/UEAmx8pPMdI/AAAAAAAADc4/7etMQiH3-Uk/s100/white20pct.png);border-top:1px solid #666;border-bottom:7px solid #3c3c3c;-moz-border-radius-topleft:2px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:2px;border-top-left-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius-topright:2px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:2px;border-top-right-radius:2px}
#primary-nav.g9{margin:0;width:720px}
#primary-nav.g12{margin:0;width:960px}
#primary-nav li{border:0}
#primary-nav li a{letter-spacing:.05em;padding:0 15px;line-height:45px;border-left:1px solid #4b4b4b;border-right:1px solid transparent}
#primary-nav li:first-child a{margin-left:-9px;border-left:0;-moz-border-radius-topleft:2px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:2px;border-top-left-radius:2px}
#primary-nav li:last-child a{border-right:1px solid #4b4b4b}
#primary-nav li a:hover,#primary-nav li a.active{background:transparent url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_IAq5-ECBds/UEAmpYDhijI/AAAAAAAADbQ/voqOSQJ057k/s100/black10pct.png);border-color:#444}
#primary-nav li a:active,#primary-nav li a:focus{background-color:#555;top:0}
#primary-nav li.current-cat a,#primary-nav li.current_page_item a,#primary-nav li.current-menu-parent > a,#primary-nav li.current-menu-item > a{color:#fff}
#primary-nav .drop .rarr,#primary-nav .drop .darr{line-height:1;text-shadow:0 1px 1px #111;color:#888}
#primary-nav ul ul.sub-menu,#primary-nav ul ul.children{background:#3c3c3c;width:220px;padding:7px 0;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:2px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:2px;border-bottom-left-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:2px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:2px;border-bottom-right-radius:2px}
#primary-nav ul ul.sub-menu ul,#primary-nav ul ul.children ul{-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px;margin-top:-44px;margin-left:200px;border:1px solid #333}
#primary-nav ul ul.sub-menu .rarr,#primary-nav ul ul.children .rarr{float:none}
#primary-nav ul.sub-menu li a,#primary-nav ul.children li a{margin:0;border:0;line-height:36px;font-size:12px;color:#999}
#primary-nav li:first-child > ul{margin-left:-10px}
#nav-bar .search-box .widget{margin:0;line-height:45px;height:45px;overflow:hidden}
#nav-bar .search-box .widget div{background:url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-x-n5CVO1qx0/UEAmtQv3qHI/AAAAAAAADcI/ArquQek6_cc/s24/search.png) no-repeat right center}
#nav-bar .search-box .widget input{background:transparent url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_IAq5-ECBds/UEAmpYDhijI/AAAAAAAADbQ/voqOSQJ057k/s100/black10pct.png);padding:6px 5px 5px;border:0;width:210px !important;font-size:13px;line-height:20px;color:#777;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px}
.ie7 #nav-bar .search-box .widget input{margin-top:5px}
#nav-bar .search-box .widget input:focus{color:#999;background:transparent url(https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vJzxhwZ7j-A/UEAmqIXnNoI/AAAAAAAADbY/EIVhtIZraH8/s100/black20pct.png)}
.menu > ul, .menu > ul li { list-style: none; padding: 0; line-height: 1; }
.menu > ul li a { text-decoration: none; }
.menu > ul, .menu > ul ul { list-style: none; line-height: 1; z-index: 100; }
.menu > ul a { display: block; line-height: 36px; padding: 0 10px; z-index: 100; }
.menu > ul li { float: left; }
.menu > ul ul { position: absolute; width: 200px; left: -9999em; }
.drop li:hover ul, .drop li.sfhover ul { left: auto; }
.drop li ul li a { width: 180px; }
.drop li ul ul { margin: -36px 0 0 200px; }
.drop li:hover ul ul, .drop li:hover ul ul ul,
.drop li.ie6hover ul ul, .drop li.ie6hover ul ul ul { left: -9999em; }
.drop li:hover ul, .drop li li:hover ul, .drop li li li:hover ul,
.drop li.ie6hover ul, .drop li li.ie6hover ul, .drop li li li.ie6hover ul { left: auto; }
.drop li:hover, .drop li.hover { position: static; }
.drop .rarr, .drop .darr { font-family: Arial !important; }
.drop .rarr { display: none; float: right; }
.drop .sub-menu .darr { display: none; }
.drop .sub-menu .rarr { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for that area of the page? Just the nav area. Also, the CSS that apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I took the liberty of examining your site's source. Unfortunately, it looks like a lot of the css is crammed into the head of your site, making it hard to work with. And on top of that, it looks auto-generated, with a lot of elements that don't inherit very well from parents. You can clean up a lot of it by moving it to a dedicated css file and referring to it.

That being said, try changing the margins of your `primary-nav` div to `margin:0px auto;` and see if that works. It should auto-center the primary-nav `div` inside its containing `nav-bar` div.

Code:

```
...
#nav-bar{padding:0 10px;bac ...
#primary-nav{margin:0px auto;}          /***INSERT THIS LINE HERE***/
#primary-nav.g9{margin:0;width:720px}
...
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry I didn't look back here to post the code for you. I honestly didn't expect an answer so soon. I've tried that code as well, not placed in between where you said, until just now and its still a no go. Thanks for the above info though. I'm not sure how and/or why the CSS is crammed up top, and auto-generated etc. I don't really know what that means, moving to a dedicated css file and referring to it, but if that will help, I shall go search out info on those topics as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Certainly! Here are a couple of resources: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners/ and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Oh, and if I did answer your question, please Accept the answer. If I didn't, no worries! Just let me know if you need more help. :)

Comment: Well, technically you answered it, but it didn't apply. I don't have enough rep to up vote it, and I don't want to "accept" the answer in hopes of getting other input. However, thanks for the resource links sir!

Comment: Not a problem, my fellow user! The css_howto directly addresses moving CSS out of a page and like all W3Schools stuff, it's excellent.

Comment: So, I finally got a result that I can live with for now. In the `#primary-nav.g9{margin:0;width:720px} ` line of code, I adjusted it to `#primary-nav.g9{margin-left:125px;width:720px}` just by chance. Changing it to :auto; or :0px auto or any combo of things I could find would not center the text(s). I don't know if that lends any help to what I could do to better implement a code, because frankly if (and more likely when) we add another page, I don't want to have to go edit that px count to offset it to center.